# AcroPdfLib: SetZoomScroll

Tags: c#, winforms, pdf-viewer, axacropdf

I'm currently having a problem with AcroPdfLib method SetZoomScroll(). The problem is that this method doesn't properly set coordinates. Zoom value is viewing properly. But for example when I'm setting `SetZoomScroll(350, 480, 10)`.

```
Zoom = 350
Horizontal coordinate = 480
Vertical coordinate = 10
```

And after compilation PDF file is zoomed by 350, horizontal coordinate is 0, and vertical coordinate is 480. I just don't know what the problem is...

I'm dealing with this problem from over a week...

Answer (score 0):

This problem is caused by Adobe version. XI and X are not working properly, but version 9.4.0 works fine. You can download it here: http://www.oldapps.com/adobe_reader.php